# Plot window not responding

Tags: plot, octave, freeze

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. Each time, I'm using plot function, plot windows will shows and draws successfully, but after that it stops responding and must shut down it.

For example :

```
x = linspace(0,1,10)
y = x.^2
plot(x,y);
```

Strangely, when plot windows freeze and I must close octave windows, they will be unresponsive too. This will not happen if I don't use plot function.

I don't know why. Does it because I'm using 64 bit version? Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh. My friend shows me this command and it works fine :

`pkg rebuild -noauto oct2mat`

The command reinstalls the package but marks it to not load by default at startup. This behavior has now been changed and new releases of Forge packages will NOT load by default.

The problem is that the package oct2mat should never be loaded. It shadows several functions of Octave core so it starts acting weird. Unless you really have a need for this package you better off just removing it.

The purpose of oct2mat is to make up for the lack of missing functions in Matlab and make code written for Octave run in Matlab. If you don't need oct2mat, remove it. No one needs all packages installed, and it can actually [make your Octave install worse](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#How_do_I_install_all_octave_packages.3F%20be%20hamrful) such as in the case of oct2mat.

Comment: Please, where should I run this command? I am using Ubuntu and the terminal does not recognize `pkg` and the Octave just says `no such file or directory`.

Comment: I had the same problem in Octave 4.0. I solved it creating empty directory 'packages' in C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\share\octave

Answer (score 132):

The problem is likely to be the graphics toolkit which your installation of Octave is using.

To check this, type `graphics_toolkit` in the Octave command line.

If the response is `fltk` and your plot window is freezing, then **switch the default toolkit to gnuplot**: `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')`

Test that the problem is fixed: `x=1:10; y=x.^2; plot(x,y)`

Make the change permanent in your octave.rc file, located in your Octave installation directory:

```
    On Windows:  \Octave\share\octave\site\m\startup\octaverc
    On Linux:     ~/.octaverc
```

---

Still not working?

- If response is `qt`, try either `fltk` or `gnuplot` (one may be faster than the other).
- If the above does not work, you may need to [install/re-install gnuplot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/?source=directory). (thanks to lukas and saurabh for this edge case).

Comment: Shouldn't the test code be-
x=1:10; y=x.^2; plot(x,y)
Note the x.^2 instead of .x^2

Comment: @odedbd: Yes, you're right.  Fixed now.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: In my case, the default toolkit was "qt", and switching to "fltk" was the fix (I tried "gnuplot" but it was terribly slow). Windows 7x64.

Comment: In my case, the default toolkit was "qt", Both "gnuplot" and "fltk" worked. Windows 8 x64.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim : You migh want to update the link provided at the end.

Thanks:
In my case the default was "qt". gnuplot worked too slow, "fltk" works fine! Windows 10 x64; Octave 4.0.0

Comment: On linux this file located at ~/.octaverc

Comment: Using gnuplot with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS helped though it is still a bit slow

Comment: \Octave\share\octave\site\m\startup\octaverc does not exist on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: This does, though: [root-drive]:\Octave\Octave-[version]\share\octave\site\m\startup\octaverc

Comment: Mac, switch from qt to gnuplot and fix my issue.

Comment: it really helps! Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

As Assad Ebrahim wrote, the problem is with the toolkit. I got another problem in version 3.8.2. that the gnuplot didn't work at all. No plot windows showed and a I needed to close Octave. If someone have the same problem, the solution is to download gnuplot and install it to Octave folder. It replaces old gnuplot and the new one is working.

And I thank you for the advice.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having and changing the graphisc_toolkit('gnuplot) to gnuplot alone did not solve the issue. But reinstalling gnuplot did! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 11):

So on windows, this worked for me:

**Step 1:**
Install gnuplot to `C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot`:

Download link:

> https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/

**Step 2:**
Goto below given directory(considering you have installed Octave in C:\ root):

> C:\Octave\share\octave\site\m\startup

open `octaverc` file present in that directory in Notepad.

**Step 3:**

Add following lines to the end of the file.

```
gnuplot_binary 'C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe'
graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')
```

**Step 4:**

Save the file and exit the Notepad. If `Octave` is open please close it too.

**Step 5:**

Open `Octave` and type following command in it to check:

```
plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6]);
```

> **Please note for the first time it might take `gnuplot` upto 5 minutes
>   to render the graph. So, please do not try to close the app. Subsequent
>   simple plots renders pretty quickly, usually under 1 second.**

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: Step 5 is what annoys me. Why on EARTH should it take 5 minutes, or 5 seconds, or even 5 milliseconds ??? It is ridiculous.

Comment: Step 5 saved me. +1! . That and graphics_toolkit('gnuplot') and nothing more. (It was not really 5 minutes but only 30 secs for me.)

Answer (score 8):

[Answer given by Assad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032494/plot-window-not-responding/25733323#25733323) is absolutely right and worked well for me too.

This is just an Exception Case.

After you type in the Octave command line : `graphics_toolkit`

If the answer is `qt` instead of `fltk`, then probably your PC needs to be installed **gnuplot** separately from SourceForge as Octave gets some errors while installing itself in W8/10.

Here is the link attached.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/?source=directory

You don't need to change any installation files.

This should work

Comment: I got 'qt' as well with Octave-4.0.3. I had to set the standard-terminal for gnuplot to windows and had to add  gnuplot_binary `C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe'  to .octaverc

Comment: i installed gnu plot separately. But still the problem is not solved

Answer (score 2):

When I first tested plotting an example graph, the graph window appeared but did not respond for one to two minutes, then the plot appeared. Further plots appeared instantly.
O.S.: Windows 7 64 bit
Octave 4.0.3 64 bit.

Comment: I experienced this behavior as well.  It looks like it takes a while for it to generate the font cache on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48247691/597487

Answer (score 0):

I have similar symptoms using octave 4.2 when running your code (Cannot close plot windows, plot takes time to appear). When statements don't end with semicolon (;) the command and result will be printed in command window. It SEEMS to me that the command window halts interpretation of code and wait for user to press a valid key (f,b,q) to contunure or abort execution. The halt point is dependent on previously executed code and size of command window, therefore the intermittent nature of these symptoms.

**Solution:**

Option 1: Go to command window and keep pressing f (forward)

Option 2: Use semicolon to terminate statements

```
x = linspace(0,1,10);
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y);
```

Option 3: Fiddle with some command window settings

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in version 4.0.3 and switching the default toolkit to gnuplot as [Assad Ebrahim said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032494/plot-window-not-responding/25733323#25733323) did not work for me. Then I find something in [Octave for Microsoft Windows](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows):

> Current octave for windows ships a not full featured gnuplot.
>   Therefore you cannot use the full features of gnuplot graphics toolkit

And there is instruction of how to download and install gnuplot. Hope it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is solution for plot window freezing when **running Octave from within Emacs**, credited to [John Lawrence Aspden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254837/john-lawrence-aspden) and [user2699](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754992/user2699) from the question [How to get Octave's plot to work under emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436702/how-to-get-octaves-plot-to-work-under-emacs). It's brought here because this question is much easier to find.

The problem might be caused by Emacs octave-mode's `--no-line-editing` switch, you can fix it by `M-x customize-variable RET inferior-octave-startup-args RET` and change `--no-line-editing` to `--line-editing`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,
Sometimes linspace is showing you all results in command windows and waits for your interaction.
add `;` after command, or hit `q` to quit in command window
`x = linspace(0,10,100);`

[image]

### Permanent solution, edited

Disable paging of screen output by putting `more off` into octave command window. This will prevent code to wait until you see all rows.

If you want turn this back on, use `more on`

[documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Paging-Screen-Output.html)

#### Related questions

[prevent-user-interaction-on-command-window-for-octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286250/prevent-user-interaction-on-command-window-for-octave)

[Can't stop execution in gui command window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006266/octave-3-8-1-cant-stop-execution-in-gui-command-window#42761024)