# 64bit version of Octave on Windows

Tags: 64-bit, octave, windows64

Does anybody know how to build Octave for x64 Windows?  The 2GB data limitation for x32 is too limiting for many problems that require analysis on large data sets.

Answer (score 3):

http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows has information on installing Octave on Windows and links to building it from source using different methods.

> GNU Octave is primarily developed on GNU/Linux and other POSIX conformal systems. The ports of GNU Octave to Windows use different approaches to get most of the original Octave and adapt it to Microsoft Windows idiosyncrasies...

Windows support is experimental.

According to http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Compiling-Octave-with-64_002dbit-Indexing.html

> To use arrays larger than 2 GB, Octave has to be configured with the option --enable-64. This option is experimental...

Compiling Octave for 64 bit is experimental on Linux. It might cause a lot of headache to try an experimental feature in a port of the software. It would be better to use a true Linux installation for now. If you feel adventurous, try compiling it in http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Octave-4.0.0 into windows 7,8 and 10 in x64 platforms. All works perfectly well.

Just follow these steps

1. Download *Octave-4.0.0_0-installer.exe* from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/
2. Install the same - just follow the steps in the installer.
3. Find the build_packages.m file in C:\Octave\Octave 4.0.0\src
4. Open it in Octave and find

   *try install general-1.3.4.tar.gz*, and *try install signal-1.3.1.tar.gz*, the versions are wrong.

   Replace with 2.0.0 and 1.3.2 respectively.
5. In the build_packages.m file find

   *pkg ('install', pkgname, '-noauto')*.

   Change it to

   *pkg ('install', pkgname)*.

   Skip this and you will have to load the packages you require every time you use Octave. Lesser load for octave though. Sometimes it may take a while for the packages to get installed, kindly wait.
6. Run build_packages.m
7. load the packages

e.g. to load the general package - *pkg load general*

*Note that the signal package is dependent on the control package.*

8. I found that the plot function got octave stuck. The answer for the same is to type in at the command window

   *pkg rebuild -noauto oct2mat*

   Found this solution in [Plot window not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032494/plot-window-not-responding)

Hope this works for u too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found Sreepad's ans is CORRECT.  I use octave on win 10  64-bit OS.
octave 4.0.0 is ok as Sreepad said,  But Octave 4.2.1 is not OK on Win 10 64-bit OS.