# How to get Octave's plot to work under emacs?

Tags: emacs, plot, octave

Using octave in a terminal window

```
x=1:10;
plot(x);
```

works fine, produces a plot window which is zoomable etc.

running octave under emacs, the plot appears, but the plot window is hung and you can't zoom. If you execute `plot(x);` again, the window disappears.

I'm using Debian Jessie, with GNU Emacs 24.3.1 and GNU Octave, version 3.8.1.

To get it to work at all I had to make a **.octaverc** to set the prompt.

```
$ cat ~/.octaverc
PS1(">> ")
```

Comment: Have you followed the "Appendix H Emacs Octave Support" http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Emacs-Octave-Support.html ? In octave 3.8.1 there is a internal function __fltk_draw__ which keeps the plot figure respondent. This is done by registering with add_input_event_hook within octaves commandline. I'm not an EMacs user but I think the above link addresses this.

Comment: @Andy, that sounds like a vital clue, but I can't find any reference to this. Can you give me a link?

Comment: Doesn't the link above guide you to the HTML page of the manual?

Comment: @Andy Yes, but there's nothing useful there. I meant a link to this fltk_draw function and its use to keep the plot figure responding.

Comment: This bug report? https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40269

Comment: I would suggest asking on the octave help mailinglist, see here http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/support.html. Plenty of octave core developers use Emacs so I think you may get more response there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is caused by octave-mode running octave with the no-line-editing switch. You can just hack this out of the compiled lisp file and everything works fine!

On my system:

```
cd /usr/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/progmodes
sudo vi octave.elc
```

change `--no-line-editing` to `--line-editing` directly in the .elc file

restart emacs and everything should be fine.

Comment: This is set with inferior-octave-startup-args, so just run `customize-variable`, make the appropriate change and save for future sessions.  No need to edit emacs bytecode.

Comment: This solution freezes emacs until octave is killed.

Comment: Found the reason why it froze emacs, and it probably doesn't occur to everyone. Emacs was kept on a loop waiting for octave to print the prompt. Octave did print it but emacs didn't recognize it because it octave didn't start the line with it. It started it with an ANSI escape sequence for terminal bracketed-paste-mode because I had `set enable-bracketed-paste on` in my readline config. One can either remove that from the readline config or edit the prompt regex variable in emacs to fix the freezing.