# Prevent user interaction on command window for octave

Tags: octave

When I run below octave code the command window displays :

```
>> first
x =

    10
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    70
    80
    90
   100

y =

   14
   17
   18
   14
   15
   14
   13
   12
   11
    4

m =  10
x =

     1    10
     1    20
     1    30
     1    40
     1    50
     1    60
     1    70
     1    80
     1    90
     1   100

-- less -- (f)orward, (b)ack, (q)uit
```

I'm required to continually press (f) to complete program and view plot : plot(x(:,2), x*theta, '-');

Octave code :

```
x = [10
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    70
    80
    90
    100]
y = [14
    17
    18
    14
    15
    14
    13
    12
    11
    4]

m = length(y)

x = [ones(m , 1) , x]

theta = zeros(2, 1);        

iterations = 10;
alpha = 0.000007;

for iter = 1:iterations
     theta = theta - ((1/m) * ((x * theta) - y)' * x)' * alpha;
     #theta
end

#plot(x, y, 'o');
#ylabel('Response Time')
#xlabel('Time since 0')
plot(x(:,2), x*theta, '-');
```

How to prevent user interaction with command window so that program runs to completion and displays prompt and not requiring
user interaction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent your variables from printing altogether, simply add a semicolon to the end of each variable assignment:

```
m = length(y)   %// **will** print to the console
m = length(y);  %// will *not* print to the console
```

To print your variables to the console, but avoid Octave pausing the output when it gets to the bottom of the screen, add `more off` to the beginning of your script to turn off paging.

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html

Type `more on` to switch it back on.

Comment: thanks,  so by default octave will print all created variables to screen?

Comment: @blue-sky Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @blue-sky no. Only when you forget to end your statements with `;`

Comment: @blue-sky While we're giving tips about semicolons, you don't have to use that multi-line format to declare column vectors. You can place semicolons between the elements and place them all on the same line: `x = [10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60; 70; 80; 90; 100];`