# octave 3.8.1 can't stop execution in gui command window

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, octave

I'm running octave 3.8 with the gui in Ubuntu 14.04. I have an infinite loop somewhere in my program and it seems like the terminal doesn't respond to the typical keypresses to stop execution. (eg. Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z) When I run programs in the terminal, I can just press Ctrl+C, but that doesn't seem to work here. What can I do to halt execution?

Comment: When you started the GUI for the first time on Octave 3.8, you should have gotten a warning that the GUI was experimental. You will notice that you need to use `--force-gui` too as well. You should try Octave 4.0, the first release with GUI as stable.

Comment: @carandraug I'm using octave v.4.0.0 GUI (ubuntu 16.04) and I see the same issue. I can't cancel a command running midway, not even with ctrl+c on the command window.

Even though it looks like it's stopped, by CPUs are still working like crazy.

Comment: Same in 4.4.1 ... Ctrl+C answer below did work

Answer (score 10):

To stop a running command or script in octave GUI or prompt:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

you will see:

```
less -- (f)orward, (b)ack, (q)uit
```

To abort (and close the GUI or command line):

2. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

To just stop printing the output of the command or script (?):

2. <kbd>q</kbd>
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the review of answer post on how stop execution in gui command window for octave 3.8.1 @kenny-evitt

Answer (score 1):

It's a long-running [bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?37672) that hasn't been fixed since 2012, run with `--no-gui` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

after going through lots of bugs report and all.

Finally by hitting (ctr + c + Enter) at command window (below the pause statment) execution gets terminated.

hope it works for u too.

Comment: but after hitting to many times (like 10 times) the whole software is getting terminated.so sick with this. installing another version will it solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully tried using the system monitor to stop the process of octave, and of octave-gui. octave and octave-gui processes are available in the system monitor.

After stopping the process, when I clicked on the octave gui, it brought a complaint to terminate or wait. I ignored that and went to the system monitor, and I told it to continue the octave-gui process (only). (Telling it to continue the octave process did not help.) Then, I returned to the gui by clicking on the command window. I pressed control+c immediately. Now, depending on how many times I had pressed run/f5, and on how "hard" it was hanging, I had to stop the octave-gui and octave processes again, by using the system monitor, then, continue the octave-gui process, and press ctrl+c, until I had applied ctrl+c on each run. Sometimes, it was enough to use the system monitor once, and then use only ctrl+c several times.

(The type of hang unending looping trouble I solved and replicated and solved was:

I had an algorithm that hangs, running without stopping, when a number was less than another one, because I did not put that test as its stop condition. So, when I ran it, I thought it finished because no extra output came out on the command window. But it was still running. I had continued to type. Then I ran my program again, and "nothing happened". I ran it again, thinking that I miss pressed something. I got nothing. Then, I noticed that it did not finish the first run. Then I applied the procedure I gave above.

This was how I replicated and solved the unending looping problem.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).