# Plot doesn't work in Octave 4.0.0 (Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: plot, octave

I'm trying to get Plot working for Octave Windows 7 (64 bit). Things I have tried:

1. Tried changing the graphics_toolkit to gnuplot or fltk. See [Plot window not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032494/plot-window-not-responding)
2. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Octave.
3. I have tried to install the latest version of gnuplot in the Octave Directory.
4. pkg rebuild -noauto oct2mat (didn't help before or after octave restart)

The cursor moves to the next line (without ">>", as if waiting for the command to run), but the figure window doesn't show at all, I have to press Ctr-C several times to force Octave to quit.

Code:

```
x = linspace(0,1,10)
y = x.^2
plot(x,y);
```

Please suggest if I can try something else.

Octave version : 4.0.0, running on a laptop, Windows 7 64-bit Professional.

Comment: and try for example just "sombrero",nothing else, do you see the plot?

Comment: You habe to wait at least 60s for the first plot because the fontconfig cache is build.

Comment: Thank you! :) I've waited for about 60 seconds and the plot (sombrero) has indeed appeared. Now all the plots show right after plotting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I rewrite the comment as answer.
A long delay when plotting for the first time in GNU Octave on Windoze is a known problem: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45458

The reason for this is that the fontconfig cache has to be build once. After that plotting should be fast as usual.

Comment: In my case in a netbook I waited for 3 minutes the firt times, after plot fast