# Octave is not plotting after upgrading Ubuntu to 17.10.1

Tags: octave, ubuntu-17.10

Octave was working fine. But then I upgraded Ubuntu to the newest version 17.10.1 and when I call any function that uses plot, it simply prints some stuff on command line.

Octave does not crash or freezes, it simply "believes" that it generated the plot, but except from some lines printed on terminal, it does not generated any graphics.

The code I'm using is to get the step response for a transfer function:

```
more off
pkg load control

s  = tf('s');
gs = 87.48/(s^2 + 14.46*s + 81.25)

step(gs)
```

No plot is shown, and in the command line it shows:
 Step Response

```
 0.1 ##############################################################################################################################################   
 0.4 ##############################################################################################################################################   
     0                  0.1                 0.2                 0.3                  0.4                 0.5                 0.6       +*******gs+.7
```

I've tried re-installing Octave and Gnuplot and setting the environment to x11, but it did not solve the problem. I appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change toolkit in Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569716/how-to-change-toolkit-in-octave)

Comment: When I use plot(t, x) the same problem occurs (it is not only for the step function)