# imshow causes figure window to hang, program seems to not run

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I'm trying to write a script that counts the objects in an image and draws rectangles around them. Initially, the `imshow` function seemed to work fine but after a while, it shows a window with a content all black and causes octave to hang.
**I think this may have happened after installing package "geometry"**.
I'm running octave on Ubuntu, and I've tried changing default graphics toolkit as suggested by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032494/plot-window-not-responding) but it does not help for me, the window that is supposed to show the image does not appear at all. I've tried to reinstall octave but this also didn't help.
Octave and the Image and Geometry packages are installed with `sudo apt-get install` via command line.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Would you like to share your script for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding pause command after the imshow command AND changing the graphics toolkit to gnuplot** solve the problem. It is interesting however that this was not needed initialy and it might have something to do with installing geometry or some Ubuntu update.