# Why does Octave show an error when I use plot?

Tags: plot, octave

This is some very simple code in Octave

```
data = load('ex1data1.txt')
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2))
```

This shows an error:

```
error: parse error near line 163 of file C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octa
ve-6.3.0\mingw64\share\octave\6.3.0\m\plot\util\private\__add_default_men
u__.m

  invalid parameter list

>>> function toggle_visibility_cb (hf, ~, hmenu, htb)
```

Comment: The problem is probably on the value of `data`. Can you look into that and tells us how to reproduce the problem? Since we do not have the `"ex1data1.txt"` file, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you set `data=rand(10,1)`? It’s always best to find a [mre] that doesn’t require a data file.

Comment: The first thing to try is changing the graphics backend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032494/plot-window-not-responding/25733323#25733323

Comment: This has been reported as a bug in the octave bugtracker, see here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=60524. Feel free to contribute to that discussion to help resolve the bug.